# Simple nginx server_name regex does not find match

Tags: nginx, regex

I have an nginx box running version 1.8.1 on AWS. I am converting numerous DNS routing conditions into nginx and have encountered many DNS entries where `*.yet_another_domain.*` would be useful, but nginx does not appear to like having wildcards on both sides of the host (that "or" in the documentation, referring to which side a wildcard can go, can be a loaded word to software developers). Therefore, I moved on to regular expressions.

I have set up a hosts entry on my localhost for both uno.com and www.uno.com, pointing them to my nginx box. Using server_name values such as `www.uno.com uno.com` or `.uno.com` gives me results, so I know nginx is capable of hitting my configuration when I don't rely on regular expressions (`*.uno.com` is another matter, having some flaws, but I digress). I've tried a number of regular expressions, all without nginx matching to either uno.com or www.uno.com.

Some regular expressions I have tried:

`server_name ~^(.*\.?uno\..*)$;` (hoping to match www.uno.com and uno.com)

`server_name ~^(.*\.)?uno\.com$;` (also looking for www.uno.com and uno.com)

`server_name ~uno\.com;` (just looking for uno.com anywhere in the host)

`server_name ~^uno.*;` (looking for a host starting with uno)

My AWS nginx instance returns a nifty nginx/Amazon test page whenever I look for uno.com or www.uno.com when using any of these regular expressions, but not the hard-coded return value I am looking for.

Comment: It appears as though there is something in a separate server configuration that is causing the problem. I moved all my other configuration files out and the regex started working. Going to start moving the other files back in to see what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is the problem. I have an include in my nginx.conf for a directory in which I have multiple other .conf files. In one of the other files, there was a server_name for *.com. According to nginx's rules for handling requests, wildcard server_names have higher priority than regular expression server_names. Now, this was actually something I was aware of -- what really caught me was that, in the event that no valid locations were discovered, nginx apparently does not go back to find other possible server_name matches. Drat.

And here is a nice, detailed description of nginx's request resolution process, that helped me to realize that it wasn't going to go looking for other server_name matches as I'd hoped:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: `in the event that no valid locations were discovered, nginx apparently does not go back to find other possible server_name matches`

Whoa, this is annoying.